# Html templates loaded asynch (JQuery/JavaScript asynch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

So I'm making a webpage with some code snippets loaded in from txt files. The information to paths and locations of the txt files are stored in a json file. First I'm loaing the json file looking like this

```
[
{"root":"name of package", "html":"htmlfile.txt", "c":"c#file.txt", "bridge":"bridgefile"},
 {"root":"name of package", "html":"htmlfile.txt", "c":"c#file.txt", "bridge":"bridgefile"}
]
```

After loaded I'm using templates from my index.html file and then inserting the templates. My problem is that its happening asynch so that the page never looks the same because of the asynch nature of js. 
Here is what my jquery code for loading and inserting looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var fullJson;
$.when(

 $.get('/data/testHtml/data.json', function (json) {

    fullJson=json;

})

).then(function(){
   for(var i=0; i<fullJson.length; i++){
       templefy(fullJson[i],i);
   }
})


var templefy = function (data, number) {

    //Fetches template from doc.
    var tmpl = document.getElementById('schemeTemplate').content.cloneNode(true);
    //Destination for template inserts
    var place = document.getElementsByName('examples');

    //Set name
    tmpl.querySelector('.name').innerText = data.root;

    //Next section makes sure that each tap pane has a unique name so that the system does not override eventlisteners
    var htmlNav = tmpl.getElementById("html");
    htmlNav.id += number;

    var htmlLink = tmpl.getElementById('htmlToggle');
    htmlLink.href += number;

    var cNav = tmpl.getElementById('c');
    cNav.id += number;

    var cLink = tmpl.getElementById('cToggle');
    cLink.href += number;

    var bridgeNav = tmpl.getElementById('bridge');
    bridgeNav.id += number;

    var bridgeLink = tmpl.getElementById('bridgeToggle');
    bridgeLink.href += number;


    //Auto creates the sidebar with links using a link template from doc.
    var elementLink = tmpl.getElementById('elementLink');
    elementLink.name +=data.root;

    var linkTemplate = document.getElementById('linkTemplate').content.cloneNode(true);
    var linkPlacement = document.getElementById('linkListWVisuals');
    var link = linkTemplate.getElementById('link');
    link.href = "#"+data.root;
    link.innerText = data.root;
    linkPlacement.appendChild(linkTemplate);


    //Fetches html, c# and bridge code. Then inserts it into template and finally inserts it to doc
    $.get("/data/" + data.root + '/' + data.html, function (html) {
        tmpl.querySelector('.preview').innerHTML = html;
        tmpl.querySelector('.html-prev').innerHTML = html;


        $.get('/data/' + data.root + '/' + data.c, function (c) {
            tmpl.querySelector('.c-prev').innerHTML = c;

            $.get('/data/' + data.root + '/' + data.bridge, function (bridge) {
                console.log(bridge);
                tmpl.querySelector('.bridge-prev').innerHTML = bridge;
                place[0].appendChild(tmpl);
            })

        })
    })
}

});
```

So yeah my problem is that it just fires in templates whenever they are ready and not in the order written in the json file.

I'll take whatever help I can get..Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only way out has been to make the whole application in angular instead and using a filter to make sure that I get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no golden method and i usually apply one of the following options:

1) Preload the files separately e.g. create key "body" for each entry in your json and then set the value of it to the contents of the file.

2) Do not display items until they are not fully loaded in the DOM and before you show them, sort them in the DOM by e.g. their position in the json array.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Gonna give the first method a try ty :)

Comment: Yeah no sorry its not gonna work.. If I understand you right you want me to put the content of each file into my json.. the problem is that all that content is code.. that is alot to escape in each file.. and would give me a problem in creating new snippets and maintaining the stuff I have :) Guess I gonna try nr.2 then